# Does Python setuptools pkg_resources module support everything pip does?

Tags: pip, setuptools, python-packaging

Python's package manager (pip) supports several operators for specifying version: `==`, `~=`, `>=`, and `<=`.

In my program, I am using [*setuptools*' `pkg_resources` library](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html) to check that the correct versions of the required modules are installed:

```
import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.require(requests~=2.28.2)
```

Does `pkg_resources` handle the `==`, `~=`, `>=`, and `<=` operators the exact same way pip does? If not, is there an alternative that does?

Comment: I figured this out myself by asking ChatGPT. Please close!

Answer (score 1):

*pip* uses the [*packaging* library](https://pypi.org/project/packaging/) internally to handle [version specifiers](https://packaging.pypa.io/en/stable/specifiers.html), so I recommend you use this library as well whenever possible.

[*setuptools*' `pkg_resources`](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html) is marked as deprecated, so I do not recommend you use it unless you are really confident this is what you want to do and understand the consequences.

I am not sure there is any other library that offers the same feature as [`pkg_resources.require()`](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#basic-workingset-methods), so you might be stuck with this.